# Java2d: using values with height precision to draw lines

Tags: java-2d

I have dificultie to draw lines with height precision.
Ihave a list of GPS position and i want to draw them with this function :

```
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(76.8936680 ,10.1869870, 76.8935910 , 10.1870300));
```

But i get only a point because the difference between the two point of the line is very small.

I hope you can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You should explain what exactly do you want to see. What is height precision?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The example show what i want to draw. The problem that it give me always one point. I tried to use scale and translate but it didn't resolve the problem. I dont know what's going on.